# Send email one at a time to multiple people picker

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, custom-list, email, people-picker

I have a list that has a people picker that accepts multiple value. I want to start a workflow that would email to all the value in the people picker one at a time.. Is this possible?

Scenario:
People picker has two values, person A and person B.

When I submit the item, an email will be sent to person A and after button click an email will be sent to person B. It's like an approval workflow.

Answer (score 1):

When Select Users: Choose Workflow Lookup for a User>While in the Selected Users:*Double Click*Workflow Lookup for a user>*Choose*Data Source:Current Item/Field from source:(The People Picker/Return filed as: Email Addresses,Semicolon Demlimited>*Click*OK>Click*OK.

In the Infopath form set the people picker to allow multiple selections and I also did the same in the SharePoint list column for the people picker just in case.

I tried to upload a picture but it was taking too long.

The most important step was the [Return field as:] Email Addresses, Semicolon Demlimited.

I just did it before commenting on this and it work like a charm.  I emailed up to 3 people with one people picker email workflow.

The logic is that you switch the data your pulling into emails and they fall in line with the Sharepoint Designer Workflow Email.

My name is Manni if you have any questions.

Have a great day and happy Solutions!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choose the multiple value you will run into a SharePoint limitation.

Basically SharePoint Designer isn't smart enough to figure out that you have multiple values and will only give you the first one (hopefully this will get fixed sometime in the future).

A workaround might be to make 2 fields and call them primary and secondary.

Then it is a piece of cake.

You send mail to the first person, wait for a condition and then send the mail to the secondary person.
[image: Limitation]