# SPD - get name/s from people and groups for email notification

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, clientpeoplepicker

I have a number of People and Group fields which are groups created within SP - drawn from our AD. I want to use the name/s selected with associated email in a workflow which captures the user/s in this field and sends them an email notification when a new form has been submitted.

Currently my workflow looks like this:

[image]

Am I heading in the right direction?

Comment: I searched a bit longer and found the answer here

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125259/send-email-one-at-a-time-to-multiple-people-picker/147488#147488
I needed to change the Return filed as: Email Addresses,Semicolon Demlimited
I apologize for answering my own questions - have a bank of workflows to create and I am sure there will be more questions.